# Inheriting PShape

Tags: java, processing

I have a class:

```
public class Shape extends PShape{
    private String name;
    private PApplet drawer;
    public Shape(PApplet drawer, String name){
       //constructor
       this.drawer = drawer;
       this.name = name;
    }
}
```

If I have

```
PShape s;
```

I would do

```
s = drawer.createShape();//return PShape
```

However, PShape doesn't really have a constructor, just a method createShape that returns a PShape.

What  would I put in the constructor for `Shape` if I wanted to extend `PShape`?

```
this = drawer.createShape();
```

Would that work? If not, how would I initialize a `Shape` that extends `PShape`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the answer you provided, you might consider choosing [composition instead of inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Basically: instead of extending `PShape`, you would create a class that **contains** a `PShape` instance. Something like this:

```
public class Shape{
    private PShape myShape;
    private String name;
    private PApplet drawer;
    public Shape(PApplet drawer, String name){
       //constructor
       this.drawer = drawer;
       this.name = name;
       myShape = drawer.createShape();
    }
}
```

And then you would just use that `PShape` instance whenever you needed it.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the source code of processing on github @ https://github.com/processing

I looked at these files:

```
PApplet.java
PGraphics.java
PShape.java
```

in the **https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/** folder.

It looks like PShape has a constructor:

```
public PShape(PGraphics g, int family)
```

So, the following should go in the constructor:

```
super(drawer.g, GEOMETRY); // GROUP and PATH work as well
```